# Is it possible to equip $R^2$ with a measure such that the measure of a curve is its length?

Tags: measure-theory

Such measure will of course be infinite on all subsets that have a positive area.

Comment: See: pushforward measure

Comment: Well, take the set of all curves of finite length, assign them measure equal to their length, and then extend to the minimal $\sigma$-algebra generated by this set in the usual way. There are really two questions then: 1. when we do the extension procedure, are all the sets to which we originally assigned a measure measurable? 2. regardless of the answer to #1, what else is measurable? The answer to #1 is usually yes (and there is a standard procedure for extending nonnegative set functions into measures).

Comment: As for #2, you might expect that this set contains the $\mathbb{R}^2$-Lebesgue measurable sets, for example, but this is not immediate, and actually I don't think it holds. On the other hand, if a given set *isn't* in the domain of the resulting measure, then you can add it into the domain in a consistent way by assigning it a measure of $\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [one dimensional Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) for this.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the Cauchy Crofton theorem, which says that there's a (pretty natural) measure on the set of lines in the plane (*not* on the plane itself) with the property that for any nice curve $\gamma$,

$$
m(A) = 2\cdot L(\gamma)
$$
where $A$ is the set of all lines that intersect the curve.

I know it's not what you asked, but it might be more interesting than the thing you were looking for. :)